# How to validate UserDefault value will or empty using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing `UserDefault` string value `! = nil or !=""` but my validation not working. How do I solve this?

```
if((UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name")) != nil || UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name") != "") {
    self.items.insert(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name") ?? "", at: 5) // Always reaching here....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if there is value for the key by optional unwrapping. Then check if it is not empty. Then insert it to the array.

```
if let value = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name"), !value.isEmpty {
    items.insert(value, at: 5)
}
```

The reason the `if` is executed every time in your case is because you are using an **OR** (`||`) instead of **AND** (`&&`). So, the second condition is true even when there is no value for the key in the `UserDefaults`.

---

**P.S:** Make sure the array has at least 6 items before you call `insert` at 5.